# Converting Python List to Numpy Array InPlace

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, in-place

I have a python list that's huge (16 GB) and I want to convert it to numpy array, inplace. I can't afford this statement

```
huge_array = np.array(huge_list).astype(np.float16)
```

I'm looking for some efficient ways to transform this `huge_list` into `numpy array` without making it's copy.

Can anyone suggest an efficient method to do this? that might involve saving the list to disk first and then loading it as numpy array, I'm ok with that.

I'll highly appreciate any help.

EDIT 1 : `huge_list` is an in memory python list that's created on runtime so it's already taking 16GB. I need to convert it to `numpy float16` array.

Comment: have you ruled out np.save and np.load?

Comment: Does that`np.array` method take too long, or does it produce a memory error?

Comment: I'm concerned about memmory , not speed. So np.array is likely to throw a memory error.
@DanPatterson huge_list is not already on disk, It's an in memory that's generated at runtime , then I have to convert it to numpy float16 array

Comment: @Ahmed: What is generating the list? Can you generate it straight into an array instead?

Comment: @Eric the list is being generated incrementally and we don't have it's size in advance. So it's being generated by list.append() method. As numpy arrays are immutable so there isn't really a point of making a numpy array directly as it won't save memory.

Comment: _"isn't really a point of making a numpy array directly as it won't save memory"_ - Not true - numpy arrays are a lot more memory dense than lists - each entry in a list contains an entire boxed python 64-bit float, whereas a numpy array contains only the 2-byte `float16` you ask for

Comment: You're not clear on whether you want `float32` or `float16`

Comment: Look into breaking the calculation into chunks.  If you don't have enough memory to convert the list to an array, you probably don't have enough memory to do anything meaningful with that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.array(huge_list, dtype=np.float16)` will be faster, since it only copies the list once and not twice

---

You probably don't need to worry about making this copy, because the copy is a lot smaller than the original:

```
>>> x = [float(i) for i in range(10000)]
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
83112
>>> y = np.array(x, dtype=np.float16)
>>> sys.getsizeof(y)
20096
```

But that's not even the worst of it - with the python list, each number in the list is taking up memory of its own:

```
>>> sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in x)
240000
```

So the numpy array is ~15x smaller!

Comment: Memory is the priority here, Speed is a secondary issue.

Comment: This uses 1/5 the memory of `np.array(huge_list).view(np.float16)` as well, assuming that `huge_list` contains floats

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've already corrected that but the point is , my machine has 32GB memory installed. The list is 16GB in size (float16), I don't want to overflow my memory by creating another 16GB copy.

Comment: @Ahmed: The copy will not be 16GB. `x = [1.0]*100`, `sys.getsizeof(x) == 864`, `sys.getsizeof(np.array(x, dtype=np.float16)) == 296`

Answer (score 2):

As I previously mentioned, the easiest would be to just dump the array to a file and then load that file as a numpy array.

First we need the size of the huge list:

```
huge_list_size = len(huge_list)
```

Next we dump it to disk

```
dumpfile = open('huge_array.txt', 'w')

for item in huge_list:
    dumpfile.write(str(item)+"\n")
dumpfile.close()
```

Ensure we clear the memory if this all happens in the same environment

```
del huge_list
```

Next we define a simple read generator

```
def read_file_generator(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for i, line in enumerate(infile):
            yield [i, line]
```

And then we create a numpy array of zeros, which we fill with the generator we just created

```
huge_array = np.zeros(huge_list_size, dtype='float16')

for i, item in read_file_generator('huge_array.txt'):
    huge_array[i] = item
```

My previous answer was incorrect. I suggested the following to be a solution, which it is not as commented by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

> You can do this in a multiple ways, the easiest would be to just dump
>   the array to a file and then load that file as a numpy array:
>
> ```
> dumpfile = open('huge_array.txt', 'w')
>
> for item in huge_array:
>   print>>dumpfile, item
> ```
>
> Then load it as a numpy array
>
> ```
> huge_array = numpy.loadtxt('huge_array.txt')
> ```
>
> If you want to perform further computations on this data you can also
>   use the joblib library for memmapping, which is extremely usefull in
>   handling large numpy array cmputations. Available at
>   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib

Comment: But `loadtxt` loads the values into a list, and does `np.array(alist)` once they are all loaded.

Comment: I checked the source of np.loadtxt in numpy 1.10.4 to be sure.
At line 808 in npyio in the method loadtxt the list is indeed specified and read shortly afterwards, at line 936 the list is converted into a numpy array via 'np.array(X,dtype)' call.

Thank you, I did not know that. I will adjust my answer asap

Comment: Updated the answer as promised. I do have to agree with hpaulj that chunking may be a better solution, but that would have to be done during generation of the data and would not have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`'s `save` and `load` functions:

You can use a normal python list as an argument to `np.save` and `np.load` will load directly into a numpy array.

Example:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
outfile = TemporaryFile()
x = [1, 2, 3]
np.save(outfile, x)

outfile.seek(0)
np.load(outfile)
```